# generating a text file in php with new lines

Tags: php, text-files, newline, fwrite, createfile

I'm having this simple php code to generate a text file with some data in lines.

```
$fileName = date('dmY').'.txt';
$handler = fopen('files/'.$fileName,'a+');
$exporteddata = date('dmY').PHP_EOL;
for ($x=0; $x<count($_POST['category']); $x++){
    if($_POST['category'][$x] > 0){
        $cat_data = $this->my_model->get_cat_data($_POST['category'][$x]);

        $exporteddata.=$cat_data[0]['cat_code'].';'.$_POST['count'][$x].PHP_EOL;

    }
}
fwrite($handler,$exporteddata);
fclose($handler);
```

when I open the file with any code editor I find data formatted correctly each number is in a new line but when I open the file with notepad I get this

```
090220179632;15678;1
```

while it should be like this

```
09022017
9632;1
5678;1
```

I tried "\n" instead of PHP_EOL but I got the same result.

So how to fix this issue so when I open the file in notepad it keeps the new line separator?

Comment: notepad needs `\r\n` as that is how DOS and Windows used to/may still do it and some apps still do.

Comment: which OS are you under? Edit: in some rare cases, you need to use `\r\n` as @AbraCadaver stated if under Windows but this could be Notepad++ related as to how it treats that file and how it treats new line characters. Check your program's settings.

Comment: Fred -ii-  Windows

Comment: \r\n worked fine thanks AbraCadaver

Comment: @PHPUser you need to use the `@` character followed by a member's name in order for them to receive notification; just like I did for you here.

Comment: Notepad++, Wordpad, MS Word and many others will display just `\n` fine.